# Reading/Parsing a .ddd (digital tachograph) file to XML in C#

Tags: c#, file-conversion

I'm fairly new to C# by the way and need to convert `.ddd` ([digital tachograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_tachograph) output file extension) to `.xml`.

As a first step I should read the file, so I'm looking at examples. Every source of information I find are using  `.txt` based examples on reading a file. The file type in my example, `.ddd`, is nowhere near that.

I'm thinking about binary read but not sure about that either. What is the correct way for this?

Comment: If the file does not contain text you need a specification for its format, and you should use FileStream and most likely BinaryReader to read it. You might need to contact Siemens for a copy of the file format specification, *assuming* that you are allowed to have one. The file format might be proprietary and not openly documented, in which case you need to google for other software solutions that is able to read this type of file.

Comment: Please add a `.ddd` example files reference here to us try to read that by C#.

Comment: The file format seems to be documented here: http://readesm.sourceforge.net/help.html#legislation, and indeed should not be treated as a text file.

Comment: I might not be able to share those unfortunately. They include data about the vehicles and drivers drive times and vehicles belong to a transportation company. I looked for some examples over internet but no chance there too.

Comment: Also, ReadESM is an opensource software which is used for reading tachograph data. Sourcecode is available on Sourceforge site but I have no experience with C++ so sourcecode is another enigma for me.

http://sourceforge.net/p/readesm/code/HEAD/tree/

Comment: For all who end up on this question somehow, I followed Evenhuis's answer and made a program to read the bytes and decode them according to ddd guides published by authorities. Sadly, I can't publish it as it belongs to my former employer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform the conversion you need to know:

- how to read binary data from a file
- exactly what the file can contain (every single byte)
- the desired output in Xml

Reading binary data from a file is fairly simple - the `BinaryReader` has all kinds of methods to access the data, especially if the data can be processed in a single forward pass (which seems to be the case). There are tons of `BinaryReader` examples out there.

What's more important is knowledge of what the data means. A single byte, with the value `0x20` could mean:

- The <kbd>SPACE</kbd> character
- The value `32`
- The byte could be the first byte of a `UInt16` with an entirely different value
- "The next block of data is 32 bytes long"
- "The first block of data can be found at offset 32"
- "The next block of data is metadata" (this byte indicating some sort of *block type*)
- 32 bottles of beer on the wall

Without information about what each byte at each position means, you won't get anywhere.

Then with that information, and having read the file into some fitting class(es), the conversion to Xml could be as simple as passing the class to an `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 9):

Very late answer but this library is in C# and supports most parts of the digital tachograph spec.

https://github.com/jugglingcats/tachograph-reader

This library provides two classes that can read driver and vehicle card binary files and write to an XmlWriter. The XML is well structured and provides a clear representation of the content of the binary file for subsequent processing. Note that the code does not check the digital signatures in the file.

From the readme:

Usage is quite simple. There is a main class DataFileReader and two subclasses: VehicleUnitDataFile and DriverCardDataFile. You can create an instance of one of the sublasses using the following methods:

```
DataFile vudf=VehicleUnitDataFile.Create();
DataFile dcdf=DriverCardDataFile.Create();
```

Once you have a reader instance you can give it a binary file to read and an XML Writer:

```
vudf.Process("file.ddd", writer);
```

Most of the sections/features of both data file formats are catered for. It's possible to modify the data file formats using DriverCardData.config and VehicleUnitData.config. These are two XML files defining the structure of the data with features specific to the standard (such as cyclic buffer support).

Comment: I have downloaded this one, it seems it is not able to read any DDD file. I get no error but the content stays empty.

Answer (score 3):

There are also ready-made solutions, such as ReadESM (https://sourceforge.net/projects/readesm/files/) or DDD2XML (https://www.canlab.cz/en/DDD2XML). DDD2XML also supports the second generation of tachographs.